# UIImagePickerController Issue in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

Hey I'm new to `iPhone` and I have been trying to make an gallery kind of app using `ARC`. where i am capturing image from camera using `UIImagePickerController`. Sometimes when i am clicking on camera button..then it is working fine but sometimes it is displaying the preview screen like below screenshot, then user have to tap on `UIImagePicker` preview cancel button and again click on camera button for capturing image successfully..Can anyone tell me the reason why i am getting this problem?

[image]

here is my code :

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You didn't set Source type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine, but I know that the UIImagePicker is resource consuming.

I think it is more optimized to do the instantiation only once. Put this in your viewWillAppear method:

```
self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;
self.imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
self.imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;
```

Then when you want to present it use:

```
[self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I noticed that it is way faster to present it this way. Let me know if it solved your issue.

Comment: @foOgThanks for your quick reply..I will apply your solution..can i give all my code for presenting UIImagePickerController in dispatch_get_main_queue, then it will work or not?

Comment: I don't think you need to call it on the main_queue, I never had to do that. It seams that the framework already ensure that it will be done on the main thread

Comment: @foOg I'm running into this same issue using the phonegap camera plugin code located here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/src/ios/CDVCamera.m. Do you know how I can adapt this code to use this solution?

Comment: The CDVCameraPicker inherits from UIImagePickerController. I am not familiar with phonegap but the solution I gave should also work with phonegap. Just declare your CDVCameraPicker as a property and instantiate it just once on viewDidLoad or init method of your class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'm not that familiar with Objective-C but I'll try my best to implement this and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

For Camera user these

```
 _imgPickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
[_imgPickerController setDelegate:self];
[_imgPickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
 _imgPickerController.showsCameraControls = YES;
[self presentViewController:_imgPickerController animated:NO completion:Nil];
```

Don't forget to import these two Delegates

```
UIImagePickerControllerDelegate and UINavigationControllerDelegate
```